# Image inside a container in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to display a network image inside a card widget. I want the image to have the width of the card and some fixed height. Below is the code.

```
ListView.builder(
              itemCount: events.length,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                        placeholder: placeholder,
                        image: events[index].image,
                        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                        height: 300,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              })
```

When I give a fixed height to the image it behaves weird. The image centers itself inside the card with some padding on the top and the bottom. I want the image be aligned to the top.

[image: the issue]

Comment: post the screenshot with [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging#visual-debugging)

Comment: change `fitWidth` to `cover` for example (or `fitHeight`) - but if you **really** want just to align it use `AlignmentGeometry alignment` parameter

Comment: i did that and now the image is covering even the white spaces. I used flutter inspector to see it in widget mode and I can see that whole widget including the white spaces is the image.

Comment: so as i said use `alignment` parameter - now it is `Alignment.center` - the default value

Comment: see the link pls https://imgur.com/a/jKq73BU

Comment: how to fit small image in big container in flutter ? Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think we need to give a width and height to the image before we can make the box fit work. The box fit property will fit the box but for that we have to define the box. Below code is working for me. I have tried it with different sized images and it always takes the max width of the card and the specified height.

The above solutions might not work for every kind of images.

```
         Card(
                  elevation: 4.0,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        placeholder: 'images/placeholder.png',
                        image: events[index].image,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        width: double.maxFinite,
                        height: 200,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
```

The above answer is my own understanding by trial and error. Please correct me if I am wrong about my understanding

Comment: `width: double.maxFinite` made my day when `context` wasn't an option.

Answer (score 2):

try this code. Call this method from `itemBuilder` it will return a card per item. In this `Image.network()` is used, you can use `FadeInImage.assetNetwork()`, also you can customize this card as per your need.

```
/*
  Get card per item
 */
  getCard(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Card(
        child: Container(
      height: 300,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 200,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Image.network(
              "url",
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
```

Comment: I don't want the card to have a fixed height. I want to add mode content to the card.

Comment: you can **refer** this code, you can change it as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set - `alignment: Alignment.topCenter,`  in `FadeInImage.assetNetwork` to make the image touch top of card.

```
   body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 10,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  //  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter, // add this
                        placeholder: 'dummyimage',
                        image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/500x300.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                        height: 300,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }),
```

output:

[image]

**with -** f`it: BoxFit.fill,`

[image]

Comment: I used you solution but like in your screenshot, the white space below the image in each card is something I don't understand. Shouldn't the card wrap itself to the content? Also when I set the height to be 200 or 100 the card's height wrapped to the height of the image.

Comment: yes the white space below the image inside the card. But  that white space is actually the part of raw image. As I verified using flutter inspector tools. If I add a text below the image. The text gets added below the white space inside the card.

Comment: do - `fit: BoxFit.fill,` whitspace will be gone. @nick.tdr